# Quotient map that is not closed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, quotient-spaces, closed-map

Can anyone help me find some example of a closed relation $\sim$ on a Hausdorff space $X$ such that the quotient map $p:X→X/\sim$ is not a closed map?

Here an equivalence relation $\sim$ is closed if the set $\{(x,y):x \sim y \}$ is closed.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is compact, then a closed equivalence relation implies that the quotient map is closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $X = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and define $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2)$ if $x_1 = x_2$. Then the quotient map is the projection $\pi: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ taking $(x,y) \mapsto x$.

However, it is not closed, since the image of $xy = 1$ is $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \neq 0$, which is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is $X$ and what is the equivalence relation $\sim$?

Comment: But how can we check that this relation is closed?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have given an equivalence. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Emily given two points with different first coordinates, you can find (disjoint) open sets around them $U$ and $V$ such that nothing in $U$ is equivalent to anything in $V$.

Comment: I saw I didn't answer this part in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1744671/4280, so I added the general facts there as well.