# Example needed to show a quotient map not closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $\pi_1: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the projection on the first coordinate. Let $A$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, consisting all points of $x \times y$ for which either $x \geq 0$ or $y=0$, let $q: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be obtained by restricting the projection $\pi_1$.

I can see that $q$ is a quotient map, and q is not an open map, but I can't find an example to show that q is not closed.
Thank you

Comment: See also: [Quotient map that is not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1744717)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the graph of cot(x) in $A$ (the set of points $(x,\tan(x))$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$).  The graph is necessarily closed and contained in A, since cotangent is continuous.  However, the graph will be projected to the interval $(0,\pi)$, an open set of $\mathbb{R}$.  We know the interval is open because of the vertical asymptotes.