# Understanding of quotient space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose (X, A) has HEP and A is closed in
X. Let f : A → Y be any continuous map. Let W be the quotient space of X∐Y given by identifying each a ∈ A with f(a) ∈ Y.

I wonder how to understand quotient space there, what is the equivalence relation and equivalence class. Furthermore, can we prove Y is closed in W.

Comment: You received two answers. Read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You consider the *adjunction space* $Y \sqcup_f X$ (also written as $Y \cup_f X$). This construction works for arbitray pairs $(X,A)$, you do not need to assume that $(X,A)$ has the HEP or that $A$ is closed in $X$.

Start with the disjoint union $D  = X \coprod Y$ and define a relation $\sim$ on $D$ by
$$a \sim f(a) \text{ for all } a \in A .$$
This means "identifying each $a ∈ A$ with $f(a) ∈ Y$". The above relation $\sim$ generates an *equivalence relation* on $D$ which we again denote by $\sim$. What does this mean? Formally a relation on a set $M$ is a subset $R \subset M \times M$. An equivalence relation is a reflexive, symmetric and transitive relation $E$. This means

1. $(x,x) \in E$ for all $x \in M$.
2. If $(x,y) \in E$, then also $(y,x) \in E$.
3. If $(x,y) \in E$ and $(y,z) \in E$, then also $(x,z)  \in E$.

Given any relation $R$ on $M$, the *equivalence relation generated by $R$* is defined as the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$. Technically it is the intersection of all equivalence relations on $M$ containing $R$. It is easy to see that this intersection is an equivalence relation (anfd thus by definition the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$).

In the above case you can easily verify that $d \sim d'$ iff one of the following conditions is satisfied:

1. $d, d' \in A$ and $f(d) = f(d')$
2. $d, d' \in X \setminus A$ and $d = d'$
3. $d, d' \in Y$ and $d = d'$
4. $d \in A, d' \in Y$ and $f(d) = d'$
5. $d \in Y, d' \in A$ and $f(d') = d$

Thus the equivalence classes in $X \sqcup_f X = D/\sim$ are

1. the singletons $\{x\}$ with $x \in X \setminus A$
2. the singletons $\{y\}$ with $y \in Y \setminus f(A)$
3. the sets $\{ f^{-1}(y) \coprod \{y\}$ with $y \in f(A)$

In other words, $\sim$ collapses the sets  $\{ f^{-1}(y) \coprod \{y\} \subset D$ to points and leaves everything else unchanged.

The quotient map $p: D \to Y \sqcup_f X$ induces the quotient topology on $Y \sqcup_f X$. The function $i : Y \to X \sqcup_f X, i(y) = p(y)$, is trivially continuous (since $Y \to D = X \coprod Y, y \mapsto y$, is continuous). Clearly it is also injective. It is moreover an embedding. To see this, we have to show that the image $i(U)$ of each open $U \subset Y$ is open in the subspace $i(Y) \subset Y \sqcup_f X$:

$f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$; choose an open $V \subset X$ such that $V \cap A  = f^{-1}(U)$. Then $V \coprod U$ is open in $D$ and $p(V \coprod U)$ is open in $Y \sqcup_f X$ (because $p^{-1}(p(V \coprod U)= V \coprod U$). But $p(V \coprod U) \cap i(Y) = i(U)$.

Let us finally observe that $i(Y)$ is closed in $Y \sqcup_f X$ if $A$ is closed in $X$ because $p^{-1}(i(Y)) = A \coprod Y$ which is closed in $D$.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how to understand quotient space there, what is the equivalence relation and equivalence class.

The construction you are referring to is known as [adjunction space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_space).

The equivalence relation on the disjoint union $X\sqcup Y$ is generated by $a\sim f(a)$ if $a\in A$ (and therefore $f(a)\in Y$). Meaning it is the smallest (in the sense of inclusion) equivalence relationship containing $a\sim f(a)$ for all $a\in A$. In particular if $f$ is injective then we only have $a\sim f(a)$ (and $f(a)\sim a$ by symmetry). But if $f$ is not injective, then the relationship is bigger: $x\sim y$ whenever $f(x)=f(y)$. This can be combined to:

1. if $x\in X\backslash A$ then $[x]_\sim=\{x\}$
2. if $y\in Y\backslash f(A)$ then $[y]_\sim=\{y\}$
3. if $x\in A$ then $[x]_\sim=f^{-1}\big(f(x)\big)\cup\{f(x)\}=[f(x)]_\sim$.

In other words we take $X$ and glue its subspace $A$ to the image of $f$. How we do the glueing is given by $f$.

**Example 1.** Consider $X=Y=[0,1]$ and $A=\{0,1\}$. Take $f:A\to Y$ given by $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. So we glue ends of $X$ to ends of $Y$. The resulting space is a circle.

**Example 2.** Consider $X=Y=[0,1]^2$, $A=\{0,1\}\times[0,1]$. Define $f:A\to Y$ as follows: $f(0,t)=(0,t)$ and $f(1,t)=(1,-t)$. So we glue left edge of $[0,1]^2$ to itself directly, while we glue the right edge to itself by inverting direction. The resulting space is the Möbius strip.

**Example 3.** Let $X=(-\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)$, $A=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=[0,1]$. Let $f:A\to Y$ be given by $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. So we simply add the missing interval in $X$. The resulting space is $\mathbb{R}$.

**Example 4 ($f$ matters).** The same setup as in $3$: Let $X=(-\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)$, $A=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=[0,1]$. But now let $f:A\to Y$ be given by $f(0)=f(1)=1$. The resulting space is a disjoint union of two objects: the first one is a $(-\infty,0]$ line while the other one is $[1,\infty)$ line with a circle attached to $1$ (a.k.a. a lollipop).

> Furthermore, can we prove Y is closed in W.

So first of all note that HEP is irrelevant here. And also $A$ does not have to be closed for the construction to work. However if $A$ is closed then $Y$ is closed in the quotient, which you can find here: [Properties of a map (attaching map) to the adjunction space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923318/properties-of-a-map-attaching-map-to-the-adjunction-space)

Comment: The link proved Y to W is a closed map, but not Y is closed in W.

Comment: @ZiangLi The image of a space under a closed map is closed.