# Closure in Quotient Space: If $\pi : X \to Y$ is a quotient map and $A \subseteq Y$, is it true that $ \overline{A}=\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)})$?

Tags: general-topology

> If $\pi : X \to Y$ is a quotient map and $A \subseteq Y$, is it true that $ \overline{A}=\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)})$?

What I have thought is that $\pi$ is a closed map so $\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)})$ is a closed set, and $ \pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)}) \supseteq A$. I am trying to prove that $\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)})$ is indeed the smallest closed set containing $A$. I have found more than one example of that being true, and no counterexample.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quotient map doesn't have to be closed.

Comment: Indeed, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744717/quotient-map-that-is-not-closed.

Comment: If $\pi : X \to Y$ is any continuous map, then $\pi(\overline{U}) \subseteq \overline{\pi(U)}$ holds for any subset $U \subseteq X$. So we have, for every subset $A \subseteq Y$, that $\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)}) \subseteq \overline{\pi(\pi^{-1}(A))} \subseteq \overline{A}$. Conversely, we have $A \subseteq \pi(\pi^{-1}(A))$ if $\pi$ is surjective, and hence $A \subseteq \pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)})$.  So we would be done if $\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)})$ is closed.

Comment: While it is true that not every quotient map is closed, here we are looking at closed subsets which have a more special form.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I appreciate your help. So $\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)}) $ is closed, in the quotient topology, because $ \pi^{-1}(\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(A)})) = \overline{\pi^{-1}(A)} $. Am I right?

Comment: Be aware: Continuous means, that preimages of closed subsets are closed. When the preimage of a subset is closed, you can't conclude, that it is closed as well. The "because" therefore doesn't work.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz isn't it true that, in quotient topology, a set $S$ is closed iff $\pi^{-1}(S)$ is closed?

Comment: It is true, that a set $S$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(S)$ is open. It is also true, that if $S$ is closed, then $\pi^{-1}(S)$ is closed. The reserve direction doesn't have to hold as the example in the link provided by @MartinBrandenburg shows.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz You are mixing things up. For quotient maps $\pi$, we have $S$ is closed iff $S^c$ is open ($c$ = complement) iff $\pi^{-1}(S^c)$ open iff $\pi^{-1}(S)^c$ open iff $\pi^{-1}(S)$ is closed.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Indeed I did mix it up, the counterexample you provided concerned the second step, not the first. The preimage being closed iff the subset is, is indeed quite obvious considering the preimage preserves complements and the property of the quotient map as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *No*. Instead of writing down a counterexample (which one can do directly, see also the end of this answer) I will explain how I came up with a class of counterexamples.

As already explained in my comment, the inclusions $\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(B)}) \subseteq \overline{B}$ and $B \subseteq \pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(B)})$ are clear for every subset $B \subseteq Y$, so that the claim is equivalent to the statement that $\pi(\overline{\pi^{-1}(B)})$ is closed. To disprove this, it is *not enough* to find a closed subset $A \subseteq X$ such that $\pi(A)$ is not closed, since it may happen that $A$ cannot be written as $\overline{\pi^{-1}(B)}$.

Since $\pi : X \to Y$ is surjective, the subsets of $Y$ correspond bijectively to those subsets $A \subseteq X$ which are [saturated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_set), meaning that $A = \pi^{-1}(\pi(A))$ holds. The correspondence is given by $A \mapsto \pi(A)$ and $B \mapsto \pi^{-1}(B)$. So the claim is equivalent to: For every saturated $A \subseteq X$ the set $\pi(\overline{A})$ is closed. And this means, by the definition of the quotient topology, that the saturation $\pi^{-1}(\pi(\overline{A}))$ is closed.

Now $\pi$ corresponds to an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$. The saturated subsets are the unions of equivalence classes, and the saturation is given by taking the union of all equivalence classes of elements in the set. We have thus completely transformed the statement to something internal to $X$. The question becomes: is the saturation of the closure of a saturated subset a closed subset? But the process of taking the saturation (and hence the notion of saturatedness) is completely unrelated to the topology on $X$. This makes the claim very unlikely to be true.

Let us look at a simple class of examples of topological spaces. Any partial order $(X,\leq)$ gives rise to a topological space with the same underlying set: the closed subsets are the [lower sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set). The closure $\overline{A}$ of a subset $A \subseteq X$ contains those elements which are $\leq$ some element of $A$. So the saturation of $\overline{A}$ is given by $\{x \in X : \exists x' \in X, a \in A ~ (x \sim x' \leq a)\}$, and the question is if this is a lower set. But since $\sim$ can be defined completely independently from $\leq$, this cannot be true in general.

Here is a concrete example: Consider the partial order $\{0 < 1 < 2 < 3\}$. Define $\sim$ so that the equivalence classes are $\{0,3\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$. Let $A = \{1\}$. Then $\overline{A} = \{0,1\}$, and its saturation is $\{0,1,3\}$, which is not closed.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer! My first idea also was chosing $A$ as a singleton set since for a $R_0$ space, the generated Kolmogorov quotient would be $T_1$, where singleton sets are closed, and you would have $\overline{A}=A$. But of course that immediatly fails as a counterexample, since a non-empty subset of a singleton set is itself. But maybe, more generally, using quotient maps given by reflectors (Kolmogorov or Hausdorff quotient) for a counterexample (where you probably don't have "good" topology anyway) could work! I haven't found something so far though.